# How can I remove CDATA from NSString programmatically?

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsxmlparser, cdata

Here is my string

```
<![CDATA[https://2134114018c95327dd42-9b7f7e536ddb2ed4dd0d87c2f0e46492.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/340x340/8663034_19227_$2014_03_28_10_30_34_3934.JPG]]>
```

I am stuck at this point. I just want to remove CDATA from this string. Is there amy quick work around for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"CDATA" withString:@""];
```

this should help

EDIT:

```
NSString *haystack = @"<![CDATA[https://2134114018c95327dd42-9b7f7e536ddb2ed4dd0d87c2f0e46492.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/340x340/8663034_19227_$2014_03_28_10_30_34_3934.JPG]]>";

NSString *prefix = @"<![CDATA["; 
NSString *suffix = @"]]>"; 
NSRange needleRange = NSMakeRange(prefix.length,
                                  haystack.length - prefix.length - suffix.length);
NSString *needle = [haystack substringWithRange:needleRange];
```

Needle is your url path